# jQuery not matching table values

Tags: jquery, datatables

When I am opening jQuery datatable in Modal popup the following code returns null.

```
     /**
     * Return the settings object for a particular table
     *  @param {node} nTable table we are using as a dataTable
     *  @returns {object} Settings object - or null if not found
     *  @memberof DataTable#oApi
     */
    function _fnSettingsFromNode ( nTable )
    {
        for ( var i=0 ; i<DataTable.settings.length ; i++ )
        {
            if ( DataTable.settings[i].nTable === nTable )
            {
                return DataTable.settings[i];
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This code is from jQuery library.
I wanted to know in which circumstances it will return `null`.

In general page it is working fine. 
In modal popup if you open modal popup second time and onwards that it always return null.
`DataTable.settings[i].nTable === nTable` this condition is not matching event thought it has same table at both ends.

Please help me.

Comment: not all browsers work correctly with this equals operator ===, try ==

Comment: I have tried but not working

Answer (score 0):

Are you recreating the table each time you open up the modal popup? (Is this a jQuery dialog?) If so you might need to fnDestroy() the old one first.

Are you destroying the popup, and recreating it each time, or just hiding/closing it? If destroying it, make sure you handle the table properly first - maybe destroy it, or move it elsewhere in the DOM you you can grab it back the next time it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method instead of old one.

```
    // This function sets up click handler for the rows of the
    // data table.
    function _fnSetupMyRowClicks() {
        //Handle the clicks for the rows in the employee table. Note that the
        //.live() is deprecated in 1.7 and the.on() and .off() functions need
        //to be uese.
        //oTable.find('tbody').find('tr').live('click', function (event) {

        //unbind any previously bound click event on the row - just in
          //case the table has gone stale or whatever. Refer to the URL
            //http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/43117
            $(document).off('click', 'tbody > tr');

            //And freshly bind the click event, note the use of .on(). The
            //suggested method by Datatables is .live(), but this is deprecated
            //in jQuery 1.7
            $(document).on('click', 'tbody > tr', function () {
                //remove the selection of the currently selected row

                oTable.$('tr.row_selected').removeClass('row_selected');

                //add selection to the row that was clicked
                $(this).addClass('row_selected');

                if (properties.fnRowSelected != null) {
                    properties.fnRowSelected();
                }
            });
        //});
    }
```